# Woocommerce - Display product category above product title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display specific categories above each of my product titles on the main shop page, the product category page, the single product page and the cart.

Using Shopfront as an example in the image below, I want to display "Nikon" above the titles of these flashes. The products are in multiple categories (Nikon, flashes, camera equipment etc.) but I only want to display the brand (Nikon) above the title. There are multiple brands within the shop (Canon, Nikon, Sony etc.) so the correct brand needs to be shown above the title depending on the maker of the product.

How can I programmatically add the "brand" category above the titles? I was thinking I could call for the categories list associated with each product within the product loop, but somehow whitelist or manually specify within the code which categories are allowed to be output on the front-end.

I have Googled pretty deep on this but can't find anything that gets me heading in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Existing product layout]

[image: Using suggested code to get categories, but is not working correctly yet]

Comment: You can set "A type flash" as child category of "Nikon" catgeory.

Comment: I will not be able to always make the brand the parent category. Is there a way to only allow certain categories to be shown, and to ignore all the others? That way it would not rely on the category being a the parent to achieve the needed result.

Answer (score 6):

This code should solve your problem.You can add this code in functions.php.I tested and confirmed its working for me.

```
function category_single_product(){

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

        <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></h2>

<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'category_single_product', 25 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the code - how can I control which category is output? As mentioned, the products have multiple categories, so I need a way to only show certain categories. I only want to output the brand categories (Canon, Nikon, Sony etc.).

Comment: You can create Canon, Nikon, Sony category as parent category then the parent category shows above the title.All other category set as child category.

Comment: I will not be able to always make the brand the parent category. Is there a way to only allow certain categories to be shown, and to ignore all the others? That way it would not rely on the category being a the parent to achieve the needed result.